# How to mount a host directory as volume in docker container using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a directory `models` which contains 4 files in it. I am trying to mount this as volume in my container like below:

```
volumes:
    - /home/andrew/Documents/models/:/home/andrew/Documents/models/
```

But it keeps throwing me this error:

`"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

I am using version 2.4 of docker-compose. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in this. Thanks

Comment: The syntax looks fine.  Have you double-checked what's suggested in the error message: `models` is a directory both in the host filesystem and in the underlying image?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to update your syntax. The short syntax is: `[SOURCE:]TARGET[:MODE]` format.  `TARGET` is the container path where the volume is mounted.

```
  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path ~ == /home/username And  container path where the volume is mounted
  - ~/configs:/var/lib/:ro
```

[Compose volumes - version 2 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/)]